# TextView и setEnabled(false). Как не пропускать событие дальше?

Tags: android, view, textview, listener

Имеется `LinearLayout` с установленным слушателем, выполняющий одну задачу. Внутри него расположен `TextView`, слушатель к которому выполняет вторую задачу.

После события на `TextView` требуется задать ему свойство `setEnabled(false)`. При этом он начинает пропускать событие на `LinearLayout`.

Возможно ли отключить `TextView` так, чтобы на месте этого `TextView` не срабатывал слушатель на `LinearLayout`?

Comment: На вопрос в таком виде тут никто не ответит. Исходники показывайте, а то ничего не понятно

Comment: Возможно `setClickable(false)` на TextView поможет

Comment: Для чего вы дизейблите `TextView`? Если только чтобы он стал выглядеть неактивным, то можете просто поставить ему `setAlpha(.5f)` и он продолжит перехватывать тач ивенты.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Спасибо большое, помогло. Добавьте пжл в ответ, немного, но по существу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для препятствия пропускания кликов дальше по иерархии нужно использовать метод `View#setClickable(boolean clickable)` или аналог для разметки `android:clickable`.

Использование же `setEnabled(false)` делает иное - устанавливает состояние, которое, помимо прочего, не передаёт события типа клика в обработчики этих событий, повешенных на вью.